# Interface function with some properties (TypeScript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, interface, properties

How can I use following interface?

```
interface Something {
 (n: number): void,
 description: string
}
```

I try writing following.

```
var sth: Something = {
    description: "Description"
}

sth = (n: number) => {
    console.log("Something");
}
```

or

```
var sth: Something = {
    (n: number) => {
        console.log("Something");
    },
    description: "Description"
}
```

But they both give errors.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly create an object which is both a function and has other properties. You have to do it in two steps, first create a function, then assign it another prop, then assign the result to a variable of your interface:

```js
interface Something {
  (n: number): void;
  description: string;
}

function fn(n: number) {}

fn.description = 'foo';

const h: Something = fn;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one of few ways. Each fits slightly odd with functions with properties but all are viable, depending on the use case:

### Create the function then add the property

There is no syntax for creating a function *with* a property. You have to do both separately:

```js
var sth: Something = ((n: number) => {
    console.log(n + 2);
}) as Something;
sth.description = "Description";
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=33&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EwAtQDmyA3gLABQyAFCAFzIgCumARtAJT0Bu6wAJgBoKyPhADOCKMAAOYYOjrIxYKSAIUAvhQpc4UJXnoZseQsgC81GvSasOFgHwlhyVwgVj0AGwgA6L+gENMgA1MgATOwA3JrsyHBiaFg4+Gox5Mq4vqISUrLyIBbIAEQAIuKSMnIKxekU7iCePv6BVJnZFXnVINHIAPR9JeW5VQXFFJlUACwADL0DyFPhQA)

The `as Something` assertion is needed here to tell the compiler to treat the function as `Something`, otherwise you cannot add the `description`.

### [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

This allows declaring everything at once:

```js
var sth: Something = Object.assign(
  (n: number) => {
    console.log(n + 2);
  },
  { description: "Description"}
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EwAtQDmyA3gLABQyAFCAFzIgCumARtAJT0Bu6wAJgBoKyPhADOCKMAAOYYOjrIxYKSAIUAvhQpc4UJXnoZseQsgC8yAPIsAVhARgAdHDFjgBEFWHVFTVhwWAHwkPsjICApi6AA2EE4x6AQ0yADUyABM7ADcPhpClCQi4pIycgr0AEQAIiVSsvIglVrkOdrkkSDRcQlJVMq4TqIS9eUgOcgA9JPINXVljZUUA1QALAAME9PIqxlAA)

`Object.assign` is typed to return `any` so the type declaration `sth: Something` makes sure it is treated as the correct object afterwards.

### [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Another way to create an object *and* add a property. It allows more control over the property, like making it non-writable, if needed.

```js
var sth: Something = Object.defineProperty(
  (n: number) => {
    console.log(n + 2);
  },
  "description",
  { value: "Description"}
) as Something;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=16&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EwAtQDmyA3gLABQyAFCAFzIgCumARtAJT0Bu6wAJgBoKyPhADOCKMAAOYYOjrIxYKSAIUAvhQpc4UJXnoZseQsgC8yAPIsAVhARgAdKJigIABSjpp0MAE8qYWpFJlYOCwA+EmDkZAQFMXQAGwgnZPQCGmQAamQAJnYAbmCNIUpkACJRCSlZeRBK8rjiZF1kxgh6SoARcUkZOQVKrXJ2ZDgxNCwcfDUS8goEkCTU9MyqZVwXfrqhkGLkAHojqr7awYbKii2qABYABkOT5Dv8oA)

The `as Something` assertion is needed because `Object.defineProperty()` is typed to return the same as the first argument. So it returns `(n: number) => void`.

### [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

Very similar to `Object.defineProperty()` but allows multiple properties to be configured at once.

```js
var sth: Something = Object.defineProperties(
  (n: number) => {
    console.log(n + 2);
  },
  { 
    description: { value: "Description" }
  }
) as Something;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EwAtQDmyA3gLABQyAFCAFzIgCumARtAJT0Bu6wAJgBoKyPhADOCKMAAOYYOjrIxYKSAIUAvhQpc4UJXnoZseQsgC8yAPIsAVhARgAdKJigIABSjpp0OeKphakUmVg4LAD4SIORkBAUxdAAbCCck9AIaZABqZAAmdgBuII0hShJkGJFxSRk5BXpiZF0kxgh6ACIAERqpWXkQDuQtcpH2ZDgxNCwcfDVi8gp4kESUtIyqZVwXXrqBouQAekPkbt3+hQ6KLaoAFgAGA+PkW7ygA)